# Iterable TypeError when encountering NaN Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, converters

I have a dataframe that contains NaN values

```
df:
         score home_odds draw_odds away_odds
0          1:0    59/100   263/100    231/50
1          2:1     24/25     53/20   237/100
2          0:2   221/100     93/50     67/50
3          1:1    259/50   251/100     16/25
.......
1970       NaN     36/25   197/100     47/25
1971       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1972       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1973       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1974       NaN      17/5   263/100     39/50
1975       NaN     77/50     21/10       7/4
1976       NaN     19/50     86/25   691/100
1977       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

When i try to convert the fractional values to decimal with the conversion formula being

e.g:

123/100 = (123/100 + 1) = 2.23

333/100 = (333/100 +1) = 4.33

The calculation is fractional value + 1

And of course leave the decimal values as is with the code:

```
def convert(s):
    if '/' in s:  # is a fraction
        num, den = s.split('/')
        return 1 + (int(num) / int(den))
    else:
        return float(s)

df['home_odds'] = df['home_odds'].apply(convert)
df['away_odds'] = df['away_odds'].apply(convert)
df['draw_odds'] = df['draw_odds'].apply(convert)
```

I am getting the error:

```
    if '/' in s:  # is a fraction
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

When I drop `NaN` values, the formula works.

I want to keep the `NaN` values in the dataframe and convert just the non `NaN` ones.

How can I do it?

Comment: Oh alright! So `str(s)` takes in `NaN` values but `int` does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the data is `Nan` (which is a `float`) in the beginning of your function:

```
def convert(s):
    if pd.isnull(s):
        return s
    if '/' in s:  # is a fraction
        num, den = s.split('/')
        return 1 + (int(num) / int(den))
    else:
        return float(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

A hack with `pd.eval`. Use `str.replace` to replace:

1. `59/100` by `1+59/100` (which the result is 1.59)
2. `NaN` by `1e999-1e999` (which the result is NaN)

```
df.update(df.filter(like='_odds')
            .replace({r'(\d+)/(\d+)': r'1+\1/\2',
                      np.NaN: '1e999-1e999'}, regex=True)
            .apply(pd.eval))
```

```
>>> df
     score home_odds draw_odds away_odds
0      1:0      1.59      3.63      5.62
1      2:1      1.96      3.65      3.37
2      0:2      3.21      2.86      2.34
3      1:1      6.18      3.51      1.64
1970   NaN      2.44      2.97      2.88
1971   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1972   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1973   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1974   NaN       4.4      3.63      1.78
1975   NaN      2.54       3.1      2.75
1976   NaN      1.38      4.44      7.91
1977   NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```